# One packet in multiple TCPstream messages

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I am writting a tool using already created API. The creator of the api doesn't know c# so he isn't able to help me with that issue (API is written in C++ but it should work fine with c# too).
In short - tool sends json messages using TCP socket. Messages are terminated with '\1' character or 0x01 byte (so one "packet" can be stored in 2  messages received from API).

and this is the part I have no idea how to handle.
I wrote something like that:

```cs
//function to receive messages from tcpserver
while (true)
{
    byte[] numArray = new byte[TCPClient.ReceiveBufferSize + 1];
    TCPClientStream.Read(numArray, 0, TCPClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
    string[] msg = Strings.Split(Encoding.UTF7.GetString(numArray), "\u0001");
    ...
    later json deserialize etc
}
```

but it's not reading packets which are stored in more than one tcp message.

do you have any ideas how can I fix that?
I made a tool with QT and c++ using official tool API..and ok. It works fine. but I personally hate c++ and "upgrading" this tool is a horror for me.

With C# it seems to be not reading part of the messages, which should be handled. I checked that and seems to be missing about 30% of the packets.

There is no official c# api...but this kind of api should be possible to work with any language which supports JSON and TCP sockets.

thanks for any tip in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: You got the concept entirely backwards. Messages can be comprised of multiple TCP packets (i.e., segments; possibly out-of-order). TCP packets _cannot_ be split. Also, you are using the Stream.Read method improperly. (Pay _utmost_ attention to the official API documentation for Stream.Read.) Stream.Read does NOT guartantee that the amount of requested bytes will actually be read by a single invocation of Stream.Read.

Comment: Since you are basically receiving UTF-7 text (or so your code assumes), you could just wrap the network stream in a StreamReader (configured with the proper text encoding), and then read/deserialize the text from the StreamReader. That would save you from dealing with the pecularities of Stream.Read. But even then you should still pay attention to the official API documentation for the stuff you are using ;-)

Comment: You  have to read until you get the '\1'.  TCP  may not come in one chunk.  Only use UTF-7 if other end of connection uses the same encoding.